# ST_Covers: Geography Implementation is not working, Geometry Implementation taking too long

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a query: (This query uses geographical implementation of ST_Covers function)

```
SELECT ST_Covers(ST_GeoGraphyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((179 -89,179 89,-179 89,-179 -89,179 -89)))'),ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(20 30)'));
```

When I run this query it **should return true but it returns false.** I don't know whats wrong with PostGIS (or with this query)

and when i changes geographical implementation with geometrical one, and **rearrange the query to be like below:**

```
SELECT ST_Covers(ST_ASTEXT(ST_GeoGraphyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((179 -89,179 89,-179 89,-179 -89,179 -89)))')),text('POINT(20 30)'));
```

**it works as it should, returning true:**

I can use below query to be content but **Problem is when database is too large it takes too much time**

Please can someone tell me

how to make query 1 to work right (as intended, returning true), or

how to make query 2 work fast with large tables

(please do not suggest that i should remove *ST_GeoGraphyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((179 -89,179 89,-179 89,-179 -89,179 -89)* because it only represents geographical data that will be replaced by data from the column of table )

other values with which query 1 dont work are (5 5) (10 10) (-10 -10) and much more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query fails because you are using a `geography` type with something >180° wide. If it were something more realistic, such as `'MULTIPOLYGON(((100 0,100 50,0 50,0 0,100 0)))'`, it will return TRUE.

There is no direct way to find the maximum diameter of the exterior rings of the MultiPolygon geography types, but you can attempt to hunt these particular cases down with something like:

```
SELECT ST_XMax(geog::geometry) - ST_XMin(geog::geometry) AS width,
       ST_YMax(geog::geometry) - ST_YMin(geog::geometry) AS height
FROM polygons
```

examine the ones that are > 180, and see if each of the parts are also > 180. If so, these should be regarded as invalid geographies.

---

The only reason why the second query returns TRUE is because ST_AsText converts to WKT, which is then re-interpreted back to WKB as `geometry` types (and implicitly calls `ST_Covers(geometry, geometry)`, rather than `ST_Covers(geography, geography)`). This query is slow since it converts from WKB to WKT to WKB, with possible loss of precision in between conversions. A faster version of this is to cast the geography column to geometry using `::geometry`, e.g.:

```
SELECT ST_Covers(geog::geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(20, 30), 4326))
FROM polygons
```

Geometry types use simple "flat earth" Cartesian logic for ST_Covers, which is why you see TRUE for what you expect. Geography types use a different "round earth" logic, which uses more complicated spherical logic, but is easy to see if you have a globe handy.

Comment: The query works fine when running it through the db, thank you. But when i save it in an .sql file to access it from the code base providing Point as a parameter, it gives error stating "Not all named parameters have been set: [:geometry]". How can i solve this issue?

Comment: not sure if I understand you, perhaps edit your question above. Perhaps explicitly cast all arguments using `::geometry`?

Comment: My Query is: 
SELECT 
*
FROM 

    geotagger.geo_fenced_events

WHERE

    ST_ASTEXT(area) && text(:point)

    AND

    ST_Covers(area::geometry, ST_SetSRID(:point, 4326))

ORDER BY create_date

and I have saved it in an sql file. 

I access this query using code:
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("location of sql file").addEntity(Entity.class).setString(string,string)

When i execute query error is: 
Not all named parameters have been set: [:geometry]

Hope now you understand the problem.

Comment: It was a simple cast issue, solved by CAST(area AS geometry). Thanks